# If $\varepsilon_t$ is white noise, then $\eta_t = \varepsilon_t - \varepsilon_{t-1}$ is white noise?

Tags: self-study, white-noise

If $\varepsilon_t$ is white noise, then $\eta_t = \varepsilon_t - \varepsilon_{t-1}$ is white noise ?

By the fact that $\varepsilon_t$ is white noise, I don't know what I can say about $\varepsilon_{t-1}$ and therefore I don't know how to answer this question. I know that a white noise follows these conditions :

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(\varepsilon_t) &= 0 \\[6pt]
\mathbb{E}(\varepsilon_t^2) &= \sigma^2 \\[6pt]
\mathbb{E}(\varepsilon_k \varepsilon_l) &= 0 
\quad \quad \text{for all } k \neq l. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

Comment: I have taken the liberty of editing your mathematical equations using [LaTeX](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics).  Can you please check that this reflects your intended question.

Comment: Hint: If $(\eta_t)$ is white noise, then (among other requirements) $\eta_t$ and $\eta_{t+1}$ must be uncorrelated for all $t.$  Because all $\eta_t$ have zero mean, the correlation is proportional to $E[\eta_t\eta_{t+1}].$  Is that value always zero?

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.

Comment: For the moment, I've only supposed that εt-1 was also a white noise which I don't know if I can assume it but By doing so, I see that the first property is okay. The second one, I obtain a variance for ηt equals to 2 σ2 so I don't konw if this condition is okay and the third one is okay too.

Comment: Being "a white noise" is a property of a stochastic process, not of a single variable. It's $(..., \varepsilon_{t-1}, \varepsilon_t, \varepsilon_{t+1},...)$ that is, collectively, white noise; you don't have to assume anything further about $\varepsilon_{t-1}$ (this confusion is probably a result of bad notation). The second property just requires that the variance of $\eta_t$ be constant which, as you've said, it is, it's just not the same constant as for $\varepsilon_t$, which is fine. You should take another look at the third property, it does *not* hold for $\eta_t$.

Comment: Oh okay, thank you it helps a lot @ChrisHaug! So for the third condition if I'm taking the example of @whuber above I see that E[ηtηt+1] will be equal to $-\sigma^2$ isn't it?

Comment: @Civic That's correct.